# No auto increment in my foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in my school project and I want to make the id subject of any student incremented automatically as foreign key. I am showing you the example below as prototype, there are two tables, when I'm trying to insert data into the second table, I get an error (necessary to insert another field id of the table)

```
CREATE DATABASE database1;

USE database1;

CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    IdTable1 INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    NOM VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(IDMEDO)
);

--auto increment is working here 
INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES ('data1Table1'), ('data2Table1'), ('data3Table1');

--auto increment is working here just with the primary key
CREATE TABLE table2
(
    IdTable2 INT not null IDENTITY,
    IdTable1 INT,
    dataTable2 varchar(30),
    primary key(IdTable2),
    constraint fk_tbl1 foreign key(IdTable1) references Table1
);

--necessary to add id field          
INSERT INTO table2 
VALUES ('data1Table2'), ('data2Table2'), ('data3Table2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **always** (as a "best practice") define the columns you want to insert data into - that way, you can specify those that you have to provide values for, and let SQL Server handle the others. And for the foreign key, you have to *explicitly* provide a value - there's no "auto-magic" (or "auto-incrementing") way of associating a child row with its parent table - **you** have to provide the value in your `INSERT` statement.

So change your code to:

```
-- explicitly *specify* the NOM column here!
INSERT INTO table1 (NOM)
VALUES ('data1Table1'), ('data2Table1'), ('data3Table1');

-- again: explicitly *specify* the columns you want to insert into!
INSERT INTO table2 (IdTable1, dataTable2)
VALUES (1, 'data1Table2'), (2, 'data2Table2'), (3, 'data3Table2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the value of the foreign key wrt to table 1 now if you enter a value that's not in table 1 column which is acting as a foreign key then also it will not accept

Simply

- Primary key and foreign key should match
- Foreign key can't be null if table 1 doesn't contain a primary key with value null